# Trying to echo a variable in a makefile but getting "missing separator"

Tags: bash, makefile

I would like to print the variable `K_INCLUDE` in a make file. This is probably very simple but the examples I'm finding online are giving an error.

Here's some of the code:

```
#Include flags
HEADER_INCLUDE = ../include
ifeq ($(SYSTEM_TYPE), Linux)
K_INCLUDE = /bla2
endif
ifeq ($(SYSTEM_TYPE), Darwin)
K_INCLUDE = /bla
endif
GLOBAL_INCLUDE = -I$(HEADER_INCLUDE) -I$(K_INCLUDE)

# The below line gives the error
echo "k_include: $K_INCLUDE"
```

Produces the error:

```
make.include:28: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

Comment: If you found any example like this, you should report it to the author as bad because that's not a legal makefile.  `echo` is a shell command, and makefiles are not shell scripts, so you can't run `echo` as a makefile operation.

Comment: @MadScientist What can I do?

Comment: Well, since you don't tell us what you're trying to achieve here it's hard to advise you.  Do you just want to print that text every time make is invoked and includes this makefile?  In that case, if you're using GNU make you can use the `info` function; replace your `echo` with `$(info k_include: $(K_INCLUDE))`.  More generally I would avoid any site that you used as an example to come up with that makefile; maybe the documentation for make will be better: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html